# SQL запрос, помощь

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, select

Есть огромная таблица table1:

```
id  tags
1   ,1,2,3,
2   ,41,26,3,
3   ,1,32,38,
4   ,51,2,3,
5   ,16,2,37,
6   ,17,28,3,
7   ,81,23,3,
8   ,91,12,35,
9   ,12,2,3,
```

В поле tags хранятся перечисленные через запятую id. Необходимо посчитать количество строк, где встречается tags = 1, например

Сама схема работы на текущий момент следующая, есть несколько вложденных циклов. 
В первом цикле считается количество строк с LIKE '%,1,%', во втором количество строк с LIKE '%,2,%', и так далее.
Циклов очень много.
Без LIKE все моментально происходит, с LIKE зависает сервер.
Есть альтернативные варианты?

Примерный код:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY order ASC");
foreach ($query->result_array() as $key => $result1)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE id_table1='".$result1['id']."' ORDER BY order ASC");
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $key => $result2)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE id_table2='".$result2."' ");
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $key => $result3)
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(id) as count_id FROM table4 WHERE tags LIKE '%,".$result3['id'].",%' AND string1='0' AND string2='1' ");
            $res = $query->row_array();
            if ($res['count_id'] > 0) 
            {
                echo 'OK';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Измените структуру хранения данных: на один id создавайте столько строк, сколько у него тегов и в колонке `tag` храните номер тега (одного, а не списка). Тогда вам ни какие `LIKE` не нужны будут.

Comment: К сожалению база уже достаточно велики, и менять ее структуру будет очень проблемотично.

Comment: Каков смысл в выборках из первых 3х таблиц ? ведь id в итоге все равно только из третьей беруться. А так то делаете join всех таблиц и в условиях объединения с последней таблицей пишите буквально `on table4.tags like concat('%,',table3.id,',%)` и дополняете соответствующим group by и получаете count(), если нужны и записи для которых count()=0 делаете left join

Comment: *база уже достаточно велики, и менять ее структуру будет очень проблемотично* Менять нужно только клиентскую часть, которая пишет в этот [censored] формат. А со структурой проблем нет. Нормализуете данные в две таблицы, а вместо этой "таблицы" делаете одноимённое представление. Клиенты ничего и не заметят...

Answer (score 0):

По-хорошему надо менять структуру хранения данных, чтобы убрать перечисления через запятую.
Если изменить возможности нет, то попробуйте вот так:

*SELECT count(id) FROM table1 WHERE tags REGEXP '^значение[^0-9]+|[^0-9]+значение$|,значение,|^значение$'*

Comment: а не правильнее ли использовать тогда "начало/конец слова"? `[[:<:]]значение[[:>:]]`

Comment: Правильней - это весьма субъективно в данном случае :) Насколько я знаю разницы в скорости выполнения нет.